# How to prevent UI lag when updating Notification while downloading file?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am currently using `AsyncTask` to download a large file in the background within my app, currently the download progress is shown as a `ProgressDialog` which is updated via `onProgressUpdate` as below:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl) {
        try {
            String destName = sUrl[1];
            file_Delete(destName); // Just to make sure!

            URL url = new URL(sUrl[0]);
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();

            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(destName);

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];
            long total = 0;
            int count;
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / fileLength));
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, NAME + ": Error downloading file! " + e.getMessage());
            return e.getMessage();
        }

        return null;
    }

@Override protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
        DownloadImage.mProgressDialog.setProgress(progress[0]);


    }
```

This works fine, however I now want to use a notification in the notification bar so keep track of the download instead (as the file can be rather large and users would like to keep track from outside the app).

I have tried the below code however the UI starts to lag badly, I can see its due to the `publishProgress` getting called alot, so how could I go about changing the background code to call `publishProgress` only every second

```
@Override protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
        DownloadImage.mProgressDialog.setProgress(progress[0]);

        DownloadImage.myNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(c)
        .setContentTitle("Downloading SlapOS")
        .setContentText("Download is " + progress[0] + "% done")
        .setTicker("Downloading...")
        .setOngoing(true)
        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
        .setProgress(100, progress[0], false)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
        .build();

        DownloadImage.notificationManager.notify(1, DownloadImage.myNotification);

    }
```

Comment: What version of android are you currently running this on?

Comment: Min SDK version is 8, but I have tested on a device running 4.2.1 and a device running 2.3.4 both with the same result (UI lags out until the systemUI crashes and gets restarted)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> so how could I go about changing the background code to call publishProgress only every second

I have done this before for an upload function that showed the % in a `Notification`, but same exact idea. Have your `AsyncTask` keep track of what `percentDone` the download is, and *ONLY* call `publishProgress` when `percentDone` changes. That way, you will only ever call `publishProgress` when the % downloaded changes, and the `Notification` therefore needs to update. This should resolve the UI lag.

I was writing this up as my suggested implementation, sounds like the OP already got it working. But maybe this will help someone else in the future:

```
    byte data[] = new byte[1024];
    long total = 0;
    int count, latestPercentDone;
    int percentDone = -1;
    while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
        total += count;
        latestPercentDone = (int) Math.round(total / fileLength * 100.0);
        if (percentDone != latestPercentDone) {
            percentDone = latestPercentDone;
            publishProgress(percentDone);
        }
        output.write(data, 0, count);
    }
```

Comment: Fixed lags for me too!

Comment: Thx, I changed 
latestPercentDone = (int)(total*100 / fileLength );
and work perfect!!!

Comment: Awesome logic. Only problem I face was
`latestPercentDone = (int) Math.round(total / fileLength * 100.0);` 
This was always giving latestPercentDone = 0. So I changed it to
`latestPercentDone = (int) ((total * 100) / fileLength);`

Comment: @AnujDeo You were getting 0 because `total` and/or `fileLength` must be a `double`. If both `total` and `fileLength` were `int` or `long` you will get 0 because 99/100=0 with non floating point numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I really liked your approach to it! I found that changing the code to the following made my progressbar update correctly. I had some issues while using math.round().

```
latestPercentDone = (int) ((dataBytesWritten / (float) totalSize) * 100);
    if (percentDone != latestPercentDone) {
    percentDone = latestPercentDone;
    publishProgress(percentDone);
    }
```